# Why use .WriteTo.Debug in Serilog LoggerConfiguration()?

Tags: c#, .net

In the project I'm working on logger is initialized like this:

```
var logfile = String.Format($"logs/out_{Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}_.log");
            var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
                //.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .WriteTo.LoggerSink()
                .WriteTo.File(logfile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute)
                .WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}");

            Log.Logger = config.CreateLogger();
            Log.Logger.Information("Startup()");
```

Which causes line duplication, so

```
Log.Logger.Information("Startup()");
```

results in

```
[18:06:02 DBG] Startup()
[18:06:02 DBG] Startup()
```

appearing in my VS Code Debug Console.

But only when debugger is attached.

I figured out that the issue can be resolved with removal of the line

```
.WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

But that is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no duplication. `Debug` is a separate channel that writes to any attached debugger. Without an attached debugger, anything written to `Debug` is lost. This way, there's no overhead if nothing is listening. Most IDEs display anything written to the `Debug` channel in the same window they use for Console output.

When you run the application without debugging, only messages written to `Console` will appear in the console. You can view the debut output *without* attaching the debugger if you use a tool like [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)